# Why I can´t find/download this app from marketplace?

Tags: apps, store

I found this app on stackapps.com - https://stackapps.com/questions/1942/overflow7-stack-exchange-sites-on-windows-phone-7

But when I click on link to download it, Zune launches with app page and there is NO download button (the one with 'FREE' text on it or with price). So I can read how awesome this app is, but I cannot download/install/try/use it.

I suspect submitting of such app NOT worldwide. Is this THE reason?

(I am from Czech republic)
Another app I cannot install is Amazon Kindle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps can be deployed to certain regions. if you check the link on the windowsphone.com site you can see if the app is available for your region.

Here are the links to the US marketplace. There is a link to go to your own marketplace to see if the app is available there:

US Store: [Free version](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/3a1ec0d0-df40-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) |
[Paid version](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/bb78a353-5423-e011-854c-00237de2db9e)

Comment: This way I really see that I have right app and that it is not distributed for my marketplace. So I need to search EN marketplace first and then look if it is available in my marketplace when I run into this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The application is not available for your region.

http://www.windowsphone.com/cs-cz/apps/3a1ec0d0-df40-e011-854c-00237de2db9e

Comment: The link you provided just stated "Application not found". Is that what you wanted to link me to?

Comment: Yes, which meant its not available for your region, yet.

Answer (score 2):

If the app you found (in the marketplace of another country; they are all separate) is not available in the marketplace that matches the [Live ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_ID) that you entered as the primary Live ID on your phone, you cannot download and install the app. It is just not available for you.

Things you could try:

- Ask the publisher of the app to do the work needed to get the app published in "your" marketplace as well. This could be as easy for the publisher as editing details of the app in [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/) and checking the right country box for your market, or it could take a lot of code updates and translation of text. This depends on the app, the publisher and your market.
- Create a new Live ID in the marketplace where this app is available and use this on your phone. This is not something I recommend, as you cannot change the primary Live ID of a Windows Phone before doing a factory reset, so you would loose all your data and settings to be able to do this. Also, this might mean apps you are using now might not be available in the new "dummy" marketplace you chose the adopt.

So basically the first option is your only real option.

I myself am still waiting for Amazon to also publish their Kindle app to the Dutch marketplace, but I do not see that happening soon... :-/